# Django, subdomains and mod_rewrite. URLs messing up on deployment setups

Tags: python, django, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a Django application being served of (say) `example.com`. It contains a number of sub-applications (say) `strength`, `speed` and `skill`. The URL scheme is something like `http://example.com/strength`, `http://example.com/speed` and `http://example.com/skill`. This is how I run my dev server (using `runserver`) and there are no problems whatsoever.

Now, during deployment, I need to have subdomains that map to these sub-applications. More specifically, I want `http://x.example.com` to map to `http://example.com/x` (for the above values of `x`) and then processing can go on.

I googled a little bit and found two ways of doing this.

- One is to get some middleware to get the subdomain part of the URL and keep it inside the `request` object passed to my view methods. I then do the whole thing inside my application logic.
- The other is to use Apache `mod_rewrite` to do the above URL translation and then let my app run as usual.

I chose the latter since it looked neater and I thought I wouldn't have to include deployment specific code inside my core application.

Now, I'm bitten by a problem which I can't really find a way out of. Inside the `skill` application, I have a named url `skill_home`. It's `http://example.com/skill`. However, once I deploy, the `skill_home` URL becomes `http://skill.example.com/skill`. Django appends the `/skill` to the top level domain and this is what I get. If I do a GET on this URL, `mod_rewrite` changes it to `http://skill.example.com/skill/skill` and it doesn't work.

My `mod_rewrite` snippets look like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?skill.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /skill/$1
```

How do I fix this neatly?

Comment: Having a universal `mod_rewrite` definition to handle mapping your subdomains to your subapplication paths isn't difficult to do, but so long as Django is appending those paths to your URLs, it's impossible to fix the problem. I'm personally only familiar with the `mod_rewrite` side of this problem, but is there no way to prevent Django from appending that path? (Well, I guess that's really part of your question, but I figured I'd ask)

Comment: Well, I thought of actually running each `sub-application` as separate top level apps and then just serving them off `/`. That looks too heavy though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this answer I'm assuming that you're willing to do a `mod_rewrite` for each subdomain. I don't think this will work for **any** subdomain (i.e. the `x` you mention).

This will strip out the leading `/skill/` so that your app will continue to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?skill.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (/skill/)?(.*) /skill/$2
```

## Update

Okay, so you want to strip out the leading part of the URL in the link itself.

Basically, that means you have to write a custom tag to replace the {% url %} tag, something like this:

```
import re
from django.template import Library
from django.template.defaulttags import URLNode, url

register = Library()

class SubdomainURLNode(URLNode):
    def render(self, context):
        domain = context['request'].get_host()
        subdomain = re.sub(r'^www\.','',domain).split('.')[0]
        path = super(SubdomainURLNode, self).render(context)
        return re.sub(r'^/%s/' % subdomain, '/', path)

@register.tag
def subdomainurl(parser, token, node_cls=SubdomainURLNode):
    """Just like {% url %} but checks for a subdomain."""
    node_instance = url(parser, token)
    return node_cls(view_name=node_instance.view_name,
        args=node_instance.args,
        kwargs=node_instance.kwargs,
        asvar=node_instance.asvar)
```

I've tested this on my server and it appears to work.

Comment: Hmm interesting... I can think of 2 problems. One is what you've already mentioned. I will have a few dynamically created domains. The second is that although the app will work, I'd still see dirty URLs like `http://skill.example.com/skill` when I hover over some links. That's kind of ugly.

Comment: Hmmm... I must not be understanding how your app is set up. I assumed that /skill/ was the prefix for the skill app. In which case you'd need it right there in the URL in order for it to work.

Comment: True. But with a URL like `http://skill.example.com`, the `skill` part is already mentioned. With a dev server running on (say) `127.0.0.1:8080`, I can say `http://127.0.0.1:8080/skill/page1` and it'll work. With the deployed setup, I'd like to say `http://skill.example.com/page1`. This will work fine. However, when I hover over the link for `page1`, I'll see something like `http://skill.example.com/skill/page1` which looks quite ugly.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is if you are using {% url %} with named URLs, Django is going to use the rules you gave it, so if the path is `/skill/page1` that is what you'll see. I've amended my answer with something I think will work for you.

Comment: Let me give it a shot. I'll let you know if it works. Your initial solution worked for me (with the problem of the ugly URLs) and I got tied up with some stuff. I'll post back here once I try. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Good answer & lots of detail.  Enough that I have decided I no longer want to do this in my app :-)